# Creating a big array C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm very, very new to C# and would like to ask a maybe very stupid question, the first language I learned was Java, in which I could do this:

```
int[][] array = new int[1600][900];
array[600][400] = 10;

for(int x = 0; x < 1600; x++)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < 900; y++)
    {
        int something = colour[x][y];
    }
}
```

Now I've searched the web for quite a while, but I've got no idea about how to do this in C#

EDIT:

Thanks for the help everyone, it's been usefull :)

Comment: If your question is whether you can have multidimensional arrays in `C#`, then sure you can http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in a very similar way in C#:

```
int[,] array = new int[1600,900];
array[600,400] = 10;

for(int x = 0; x < 1600; x++)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < 900; y++)
    {
        int something = colour[x,y];
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if I understand what's the purpose of the code in the double for cycle. I suppose those three pieces of code don't have anything in common.

Comment: It's basicly for making a z-buffer, which contains the depth of all the pixels of my screen.

Comment: Of course, I understand :)) I was looking for a connection between those three pieces of code.

Answer (score 4):

Just use a comma :

```
int[,] array = new int[1600,900];
array[600,400] = 10;
//...
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use implicit typing?

Answer (score 0):

```
int [,] array = new int[1600,900];
```

Answer (score 0):

To add some color to the answers:
  In .NET, an `int[][]` is a *jagged array*, or an *array of arrays*.  While this may be a perfectly good structure for you to use, it has the addded overhead that *each array must be initialized individually*.  So your initialization would be:

```
int[][] array = new int[1600][];
for(int i=0;i<array.Length;i++)
    array[i] = new int[900];
```

now you can access an individual value by using

```
array[600][400] = 10;
```

One benefit of using jagged arrays is that the "interior" array can be different sizes.  If you don;t need that flexibility than using a rectangular (`[,]`) array may be a better option for you.